# Foreach over an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like ask on my problem with formatting array. I'm importing data to system from .XLSX. Function return me array which one looks like:

[Array Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLOHG.png)

My question is how I can insert this data to table if I know array with index 1 and with number 1 is Name e.t.c?

I can write SQL but I can't write foreach. I already tried make some foreach but without success.

Comment: _I already tried make some foreach_ - show us what you tried.

Comment: Don't include an image of your array, include the _text_ of your array into the question.

Comment: As you will want to exclude row 0 with the headers, this kind of foreach should be the right one: `$count = count($array); for($i=1; $i<$count; ++$i) { //do something with $array[$i]` }

Comment: Use `foreach` but first `$headings = array_shift($spreadsheet);`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you one more time

Here is solution:

```
/** @var int $count */
    $count = count($spreadsheet);

    $s = array();
    for($i = 1; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        $s = $spreadsheet[$i];
    }

    return $s;
```

Comment: Maybe you want `$s[] = $spreadsheet;` ? Or do you really want the last spreadsheet?